# unix redirect tail to file

Tags: file, unix, redirect, tail

I store data from a nc output in a file 24/7 hours. It is a datalogger of temperature. 
This file `amroutput` will be over the time very big. (Every 10 seconds a line).
For one app I will have the last entry in a file `amr_last_output`.
So I use:

```
 tail -f -n1 amroutput > amr_lastoutput.
```

With `>` i will overwrite the file `amr_lastoutput` everytime when tal make an output.
On mac osx we are the output of tail to the output file is appended, as in `>>` command.
What can I do?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying `>>` doesn't do what you'd expect on your Unix system?  It should work the same as it does on Mac OSX (appending to the file).

Comment: You probably don't want to use `-f` (follow) for this.

Comment: I will have an overwriting mode (>) for tail output on a file, not the append mode (>>). there two processes in backround, the first:' nc 192.168.x.x 10001>amroutput&' and the second: tail -f -n1 amroutput>amr_lastoutput&'

Comment: Just to clarify, on your Max OSX machine, the > redirect is appending to the end of your 'amr_lastoutput' file instead of replacing the entire file with the last line of 'amroutput' as you would usually expect?

Comment: yes, the > redirect is appending. I will use the amr_lastoutput to show the actually temperatures in a screen and read out the file permanent all 10 secs. over tcp/ip. If the file is big I have unnecessarily large traffic on network.

Comment: `>` is not appending.  When you execute `tail -f ... > ...`, the output file is truncated, but the command is long running and `tail -f ` is continually writing data to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am waiting for your confirmation to my previous comment. But in the meantime, I am going to assume the affirmative and give you a suggested solution.

Placing a ! at the end of the > or >> redirects will turn off the default "noclobber" switch that prevents overwriting an existing file:

```
tail -f -n1 amroutput >! amr_lastoutput
```

If this does not work for you, let me know and we can try something else.

Comment: sorry, I haven't confirm your comment. tail without -f and the '>!' also does not work.

Comment: the >! option store the output of tail in a file named '!' in appending mode

Answer (score 0):

the redirect '>' of tail only one times overwrite to a output file.
I use the while loop with sleep and run the tail command periodically.

Thanks for all!